# Двойное условие

Tags: jquery, javascript

Имеется скрипт, который безупречно работает. Но когда я задаю двойное условие, он выдает ошибку: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list.
Т.е., при

```
if ($('.myclass').length > 1)
```

Все работает отлично.

При

```
if ($('h3:contains('Текст')') && $('.myclass').length > 1)
```

Не работает. Прошу Помощи!!!

Comment: Либо заэкрнируйте кавычки
$('h3:contains(\'Текст\')')

Comment: Либо заменить другие кавычки:

         if ($('h3:contains("Текст")') && $('.myclass').length > 1)

Либо без них

         if ($('h3:contains(Текст)') && $('.myclass').length > 1)

Либо экранированием, как сказали выше.

Comment: ох... главная ошибка не в кавычках

   if ($('h3:contains("Текст")').length && $('.myclass').length > 1)

Answer (score 1):

`$('h3:contains('Текст')')` тоже селектор да ещё и кавычки кривые,  (надо в чтобы внутренние кавычки отличались от внешних)

```
if ($('h3:contains("Текст")').length && $('.myclass').length > 1)
```

вы кстати уверенны что `.myclass` должно быть два и больше ?

Comment: Спасибо. Да, уверен. Но что-то не помогает сие действие.

Comment: Повторяя полностью условие:
if ($('h3:contains("Текст")').length && $('.myclass').length > 1)
if ($('h3:contains("Текст2")').length && $('.myclass').length > 1).
Это понятно. А сразу добавить можно?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22929958/815386